# Divide the loading of a php page into several sections

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a project that consists of two PHP pages, one page contains PHP functions and the other page contains an HTML table where the table cells are represented by the output values of the functions with different variables, something like this:

> funcions.php

```
<?php 
 function A($b , $c){
   some codes
 }
 function B($d , $e){
   some codes
 }
 function C($f , $g){
   some codes
 }
 function D($h , $i){
   some codes
 }
 and other functions
 ?>
```

> index.php

```
    <?php include 'functions.php'; ?>
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Col-1</th>
        <th>Col-2</th>
        <th>Col-3</th>
        <th>Col-4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php A("50" , "60");?></td>
        <td><?php B("40" , "600");?></td>
        <td><?php C("120" , "2260");?></td>
        <td><?php D("820" , "240");?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php A("670" , "110");?></td>
        <td><?php B("4500" , "5500");?></td>
        <td><?php C("220" , "2160");?></td>
        <td><?php D("420" , "7640");?></td>
    </tr>

    ....
    100 Rows
    ...

    </table>
```

When I open the `index.php` page, the functions are gradually executed by the server and the table is created.

My problem is that due to the long execution time of these functions, I sometimes encounter a 504 error and the table is displayed incompletely to the user and the user is forced to reload the page again.

So I wanted to see if there is  a way to Using Ajax or another method of loading, to divide this table into two or more sections, so that when the `index.php` page opens, the top 5 rows will be loaded and a button will be displayed to the user, if desired, after hitting That button, the server will go to execute the next functions and as a result, for example, the other 5 rows of the table will be displayed to the user and the button will be displayed again to display the next 5 rows of the table and this process will continue until the table Be made complete.

I hope I was able to get what I meant :)

Comment: How are these functions called and where the values for the variables come from? Of course you can use ajax, to call a PHP method from some file, send with the call some data and get a result. So short answer for your question is YES, there is a way to do it with ajax!

Comment: @AngelDeykov  Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with Ajax coding, Variables are entered manually by me, for example A("670" , "110");

Comment: What are the functions doing? It seems to me that it might be better to look Into those and try to  check the efficiency, even if you have to create a hundred table rows, I wouldn't expect that to time out a webpage

Comment: @jameson2012  they are simple php html dom functions which load data from several sites

Comment: Ahh I see, so they all make external api calls? Ajax would definitely be the way to go for that

Comment: i know ajax is the way, but how?! @jameson2012

Comment: @Milad there are no end of tutorials on the Web about how to use Ajax - so is about helping with specific issues with your code and not a tutorial site.  Just Google how to get started with ajax and that will start you off

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>Col-1</th>
    <th>Col-2</th>
    <th>Col-3</th>
    <th>Col-4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php A("50" , "60");?></td>
    <td><?php B("40" , "600");?></td>
    <td><?php C("120" , "2260");?></td>
    <td><?php D("820" , "240");?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php A("670" , "110");?></td>
    <td><?php B("4500" , "5500");?></td>
    <td><?php C("220" , "2160");?></td>
    <td><?php D("420" , "7640");?></td>
</tr>

....
100 Rows
...

</table>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.